# How to add bootstrap tab menu horizontally

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have used below code to get bootstrap tabs. I get the output as below:

[image]

Can I use above same code to get a horizontal tab list after click `web` instead of vertical menu? I need output as below:

[image]

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>



<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h3>A demo of Bootstrap Tabs</h3>

    <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
      <li class="active"><a href="#hometab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#javatab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Java</a></li>
      <li><a href="#csharptab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">C#</a></li>
      <li><a href="#mysqltab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">MySQL</a></li>

      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Web <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#jquerytab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">jQuery</a></li>
          <li><a href="#bootstab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Bootstrap</a></li>
          <li><a href="#htmltab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">HTML</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </li>

    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="hometab">Write something for home tab</div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="javatab">The Java is an object-oriented programming language that was developed by James Gosling from the Sun Microsystems in 1995.
      </div>
      
      <div class="tab-pane" id="csharptab">C# is also a programming language</div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="mysqltab">MySQL is a databased mostly used for web applications.</div>

      <div class="tab-pane" id="jquerytab">jQuery content here </div>
      
      <div class="tab-pane" id="bootstab">Bootstrap Content here
        <ul>
          <li>Bootstrap forms</li>
          <li>Bootstrap buttons</li>
          <li>Bootstrap navbar</li>
          <li>Bootstrap footer</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="htmltab">Hypertext Markup Language</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Do I need some more libraries to do this? Is this existing method(which can get from the library) is limited to that type of output only

Comment: Your list markup is faulty. There's an extra closing item tag.

Comment: Also, jQuery 1.10 is comically old (2013). You can probably update to v3 without issue. At least update to 1.12 (which is 3 years newer) if you can.

Comment: Are you really stuck on v3? Bootstrap 4 was released in 2015. Version 3 is no longer supported.

Comment: @isherwood Done.. No need to stuck for 3.. I would rather like an answer(if newer version also available it also ok) than stuck with my original code and libraries...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add this css code:

```
.open>.dropdown-menu {
    display: flex !important; /* Use "important" if your css code before bootstrap lib loaded */
}
```

Comment: This probably not provides a solution. This will display the menu always. I need to show the menu when that particular tab clicked only..

Comment: I did update my answer, try again

Comment: Still same issue...

Comment: Still display the menu without clicking on web?

Comment: Now it is not showing.. but now I could not find the horizontal menu when clicked. Now it is vertical as same as before..

Comment: Change `display: flex;` to `display: flex !important;`, Don't forget hard refresh on browser.

Comment: It worked.. Thanx... Update your answer then I can upvote and accept